# To get all the row values using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the below code I have a table with `textbox` and `dropdownlist` and I can create new rows dynamically.

Now I want to get all the row values.  I tried the following code but it is only getting the first row.

```
$(function () {
    $("#Button1").click(function (event) {

        // Prevents Form Submission as you want to save data via AJAX
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "NewFile.aspx/InsertData",
            data: "{'Quantity':'" + $("#<%=txtQty.ClientID%>").val() + "','ProductID':'" + $("#<%=ddlProduct.ClientID%>").val() + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: "true",
            cache: "false",
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Success");
                // On success
            },
            Error: function (x, e) {
                alert("Fail");
                // On Error
            }
        });
    });
})

<table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" runat="server">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk" runat="server"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txtQty" runat="server"/></td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server"  Style="width: 100%; height:23px" ></asp:DropDownList>   
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>   

<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Save  New" type="submit" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: what does `get all the row values` mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Iterate through every row before the ajax call and store the values of your fields in objects and append them to your data field. Use $('#dataTable tr').each() to iterate through them.

Comment: @charlietfl  If i have 3 rows in table i want to get 3 rows

Comment: Obviusly you are getting only the first values, because you never go to throw the table.

Comment: `data : $(this).serialize(),`

Comment: I suspect you're going to run into problems with your `id` values if that table is getting multiple rows created server-side.  `id`s need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're generating your table using ASP.NET. $("#<%=item.ClientID%>") gets you a single item. I find it very useful to use $('[id*="item"]') to find objects that contain a specific text in the generated ASP.NET id. If all your text boxes contain the same text in their id, you can get an array of `txtQty` values like this:

```
var values = $('[id*="txtQty"]').map(function(index) {
    return $(this).val(); 
});
```

And you can find other values similarly.

**UPDATE**

```
data: { 
         quantites: $('[id*="txtQty"]').map(function() { return $(this).val(); }),
         // ...
}
```

**UPDATE**  (based on @charlietfl's comment)

```
var rows = $("#<%=dataTable.ClientID%> tr").map(function() {
    return {
        quantity: $(this).find('[id*="txtQty"]').val(),
        // ...
    };
});
```

Comment: I don't see how this would help directly as it won't isolate rows

Comment: @Developer: You can store these values in variables before your ajax call and then send them as your post data.

Comment: As @charlietfl noted it would be much better if you put some kine of id in your rows (when they are being generated in server-side) so that you can differentiate them when data is returned.

Comment: @charlietfl I thought you where referring to the problem of associating the returned values with actual objects. What do you mean by "mapping rows"?

Comment: map rows to return an object for each row that would then be pushed to a full array representation of the data for whole table